# Looking to implement thousand separator in spotfire custom expression

Tags: regex, spotfire

I had a use case to concatenate two aggregated values like
`concatenate(sum([column1]),"(",sum([column2]),")")` and getting value like for example 6(413892)but i need to show values in braces with thousands separator like this 6(413,892) currently it is not possible with the visualization properties formatting option because it is string now after concatenating those two aggregations 
can some one help me out with this 
i thought of  using regular expression and show it in thousand separator formatting but not yet successful
Thanks

Comment: ',' is not only the thousands separator, but a comma in the sentence. If you cannot use it, split your text into small sentences, separated by '.' (point), please. Use them, too, at the end of every sentence. Now your question is unreadable. If you cannot explain your problem to people, you have absolutely no chance to explain it to any SW.

Comment: Each question here should contain 4 points: What are your source data, What should be the result, What you have already done, What problem do you have.

Comment: Regexes are for reading and checking data, not for writing them. It seems, you need not regex, but format.

Comment: I'm assuming you created a calculated column with this value which means you are breaking the first rule of data and that is mixing / removing the data types. But, you can't expect spotfire to take a string and format it as a number. There is a potential way to do this, but we'd need to know the maximum number of digits inside and outside the parentheses.

Comment: okay for now we will consider String(sum([columnA])) which will result in 413892 (string) and need to have thousands separator for this